# Who called atexit()?

Tags: c, debugging, exit

I have a C program that quits unexpectedly on Linux and I have a hard time finding out why (no core dump, see [XIO: fatal IO error 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790890/xio-fatal-io-error-11)). I placed an atexit() at the beginning of the program and the callback function is indeed being called when the crash happens.

How can I know what called the atexit callback function? From reading the man page, atexit is called at exit (d'ho!) or return from main. I can exclude the latter because there are a bunch of printf at the end of the main and I don't see them. And I can exclude the former simply because there aren't any exit() in my program.

That leaves only one solution: exit is being called from a library function. Is that the only possibility? And how can I know from where? Is it possible to print out a stack trace or force a core dump from inside the atexit callback?

Comment: Which platform are you targeting ? Windows, Linux, other ? We may find specific API functions that will help you.

Comment: "I have a C program that quits unexpectedly on Linux" i guess he's targeting linux?

Comment: Put something *really* bad in your current `atexit` function. Divide-by-zero? Stack over/underflow? Memory allocation failure? (Unfortunately I only get these kind of errors by accident, never on purpose, so I cannot recommend any method in particular.)

Comment: Regarding your forcing a core dump question, there is ***[good discussion here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17965/645128)*** about how to do that.

Comment: If your program is unexpectedly quitting, it may not call exit() at all. You can use `ltrace -S` to watch the program's execution until it quits, then use a debugger to plant a breakpoint at a point that is just before it quits, and examine things in more detail.

Comment: I tried ltrace but the exit seems to be called from a library function, which ltrace skips over. Haven't tried -S though. The problem may be the log size (prog runs for several days before it crashes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call e.g. abort() in your atexit handler, and inspect the coredump in gdb. The gdb backtrace command shows you where it exits, if the atexit handler is run. Here's a demonstration:

```
#include <stdlib.h>


void exit_handler(void)
{
    abort();
}

void startup()
{
#ifdef DO_EXIT
    exit(99);
#endif
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    atexit(exit_handler);

    startup();

    return 0;
}
```

And doing this:

```
$ gcc -DDO_EXIT -g atexit.c
$ ulimit -c unlimited
$ ./a.out
Aborted (core dumped)
$ gdb ./a.out core.28162
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora 7.7.1-19.fc20
..
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0xb77d7424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.18-16.fc20.i686
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb77d7424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x42e1a8e7 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x42e1c123 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x0804851b in exit_handler () at atexit.c:6
#4  0x42e1dd61 in __run_exit_handlers () from /lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x42e1ddbd in exit () from /lib/libc.so.6
#6  0x0804852d in startup () at atexit.c:12
#7  0x08048547 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfc39fb4) at atexit.c:21
```

As expected, it shows startup() calling exit.

You can ofcourse debug this interactively too, start your program in gdb and set a breakpoint in the atexit handler.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the abort function.

Answer (score 4):

The standard only says "at normal program termination", so maybe on Linux this is more than `exit` or `return` from `main`. Also you forgot `pthread_exit`, which also may terminate the thread of `main` and thus the whole program.

In any case, there is no way to see immediatly from where the termination was issued. The `atexit` handlers are usually called by the initializtion function. By definition all other application code, but the `atexit` handlers are gone at that point.

You could try to trace execution through a debugger no nail the place where the termination happens down.