# Cannot run JavaFX app on docker for more than a few minutes

Tags: spring-boot, docker, opengl, javafx, nvidia

I developed an application used as a communication service for a separate web app.  I had 0 issues "dockerizing" the web app but the service is proving to be a nightmare.  It is based on JavaFX and there is a property that can be set by the user in the config file that makes it so the app does not initialize any windows, menus, containers, etc.  This "headless" mode (not sure that is truly headless...) effectively turns the service app into a background service.  Let me also preface this by saying that the app works absolutely flawlessly when run on my windows 10 machine and that i have deployed it on several other machines (all non-dockerized) with no issues.

Here is the dockerfile i came up with :

```
FROM openjdk:13.0.1-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libgtk-3-0 libglu1-mesa -y && apt-get update
VOLUME /tmp
ADD Some_Service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar Some_Service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD lib lib
ADD config.properties config.properties
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "--module-path", "lib/javafx-sdk-13", "-jar", "Some_Service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I then use this command to build the container :

```
docker run -t --name Some_Service -e DISPLAY=192.168.1.71:0.0 -e SERVICE_HOME= --link mySQLMD:mysql some_service
```

Assuming VcXsrv is running on my PC, the app start correctly, although it does give these warnings when first starting :

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4
```

The issue is that it only works for like 2 minutes.  Eventually the container comes up with this error and crashes :

```
Gdk-Message: 15:28:54.770: java: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server 192.168.1.71:0.0.
```

I understand the initial messages are due to the container having no NVidia driver but the fallback to the software pipeline seems to work fine.  Honestly I have no idea what the fatal IO error could be caused by.  I have tried on different hosts running docker and the same issue happens.

Any idea how to fix this?  Even better, any idea how to make a JavaFX app TRULY headless and not even require any of this stuff to be initialized?  When running headless, i use Tasks and such which are part of JavaFX so I can't just not use it...

Comment: Have tried bind-mounting the hosts Xserver in the containers runtime (i.e. `-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix`)? The app trying to attach to the Xserver suggests that it's not "headless", would need to review the implementation.

Comment: try to run with GPU support.

"docker run -t --name Some_Service --gpus all -e DISPLAY=192.168.1.71:0.0 -e SERVICE_HOME= --link mySQLMD:mysql some_service"

Comment: @arshpreet this gives me this error : Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]]

Comment: @masseyb I am running docker on a Windows machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install xvfb in your container this create a virtual screen. 
  change to Docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:13.0.1-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libgtk-3-0 libglu1-mesa xvfb -y && 
apt-get update
VOLUME /tmp
ADD Some_Service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar Some_Service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD lib lib
ADD config.properties config.properties
apt-get install xvfb
ENV DISPLAY=:99
ADD run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod a+x /run.sh
CMD /run.sh
```

Add new bash Script in your project folder and name it "run.sh"

run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#remove old 
rm /tmp/.X99-lock #needed when docker container is restarted
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 640x480x8 -nolisten tcp &
java --module-path lib/javafx-sdk-13 -jar Some_Service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Dont forget to remove `-e DISPLAY=192.168.1.71:0.0` from your docker run command

Comment: Can you show me how to change the entry point from a java -jar command to a command containing both the java -jar statement and the xvfb command?

Comment: I tried the method described here : https://success.docker.com/article/use-a-script-to-initialize-stateful-container-data.  This is giving me the following error : standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Comment: sorry i'm not very good with unix yet :(  I am getting this error when doing the docker run command now : /bin/sh: 1: /run.sh: not found

Comment: you need to create the file 'run.sh' where your other files are stored like your snapshot.jar

Comment: i got that part at least haha, I did do that and the docker build command does indeed see it and add it to the image

Comment: i thought docker can't add run.sh to the image. you can change "CMD /run.sh"  to ENTRYPOINT [ "/run.sh" ]. both is working for me

Comment: ugh, different error now.  Sorry to drag this for so long : docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"run.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Comment: found this answer on another post, could that be it?

It is because you checkout files from github in windows end of line style \r\n

You need manually convert EOL style to \n for all .sh/.bash files

Comment: yep that was it, and so far this appears to work flawlessly.  I believe you may have just made my day my friend

Comment: here, have some bounty!

Comment: Quick question, i noticed that if i restart the container i get an error as if the virtual screen was already running.  Do you know of a way to prevent this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204069/discussion-between-leachim742-and-martin).